# Plyr - Seeking does not work with custom HTML on audio element in IOS

Tags: php, jquery, ios, plyr

I created a plyr audio instance using custom HTML controls [from the document here](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/controls.md#example-1)

Expected result : the audio player seeks to touched part of the input range.

Problem : the audio player pauses briefly and does not seek in IOS safari.

Tested enviroment: 
Operating System: iOS
Version: 12

Here is link code pen to show this problem : https://codepen.io/dophuong/pen/mdbqRox

```
const controls = '
      <div class="plyr__controls">
                    <button type="button" class="plyr__controls__item plyr__control" aria-label="Play" data-plyr="play">
                            <svg class="icon--pressed" role="presentation" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#plyr-pause"></use></svg>
                            <svg class="icon--not-pressed" role="presentation" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#plyr-play"></use></svg>
                            <span class="label--pressed plyr__sr-only">Pause</span>
                            <span class="label--not-pressed plyr__sr-only">Play</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="plyr__controls__item plyr__progress__container">
                            <div class="plyr__progress">
                                    <input data-plyr="seek" class="plyr__progress--seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" autocomplete="on" role="slider" aria-label="Seek" id="plyr-seek-{id}" aria-valuemin="0" style="user-select: none; touch-action: manipulation;">
                                    <progress class="plyr__progress__buffer" min="0" max="100" value="0" role="progressbar">% buffered</progress>
                                    <span role="tooltip" class="plyr__tooltip">00:00</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
      ';

const player = new Plyr('#player', {controls});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @borchvm!
I mean when I created a plyr audio instance with a custom controls, the audio player pauses briefly and does not seek in IOS safari, but I expect audio player seeks to touched part of the input range. This is link to see this problem https://codepen.io/dophuong/pen/mdbqRox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this problem, I used [RangeTouch](https://github.com/sampotts/rangetouch) to fix it

```
const controls = '
      <div class="plyr__controls">
                    <button type="button" class="plyr__controls__item plyr__control" aria-label="Play" data-plyr="play">
                            <svg class="icon--pressed" role="presentation" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#plyr-pause"></use></svg>
                            <svg class="icon--not-pressed" role="presentation" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#plyr-play"></use></svg>
                            <span class="label--pressed plyr__sr-only">Pause</span>
                            <span class="label--not-pressed plyr__sr-only">Play</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="plyr__controls__item plyr__progress__container">
                            <div class="plyr__progress">
                                    <input data-plyr="seek" class="plyr__progress--seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" autocomplete="on" role="slider" aria-label="Seek" id="plyr-seek-{id}" aria-valuemin="0" style="user-select: none; touch-action: manipulation;">
                                    <progress class="plyr__progress__buffer" min="0" max="100" value="0" role="progressbar">% buffered</progress>
                                    <span role="tooltip" class="plyr__tooltip">00:00</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
      ';

const player = new Plyr('#player', {controls});
const ranges = RangeTouch.setup('input[type="range"]', {});
```

I fixed it in : https://codepen.io/dophuong/pen/mdbqRox